# Mechanisms to convert linear motion to rotation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

These are the mechanisms I'm aware of:

- Crankshaft
- Scotch yoke
- cam-shaft
- wobble drive (a.k.a nutator or Z-crank)
- swash-plate

What are other mechanisms to convert linear motion to rotation?