Coverting rotational to linear movement
What are the different methods to covert rotational to linear motion in the example below?
The servo motor will rotate causing the metal rod to move in a linear motion as seen below.
Linear motion change is will be in the order of milliseconds


a threaded rod would work ... you did not say how fast you want the metal rod to move

I would like the a several full movement of linear motion to be in milliseconds

please provide all information

which additional information do you require ?

What is the mass of the thing you need to move, what is the stroke of the movement and how fast you need to accelerate.

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/mechanisms-to-convert-linear-motion-to-rotation/60931#60931

@ericnutsch thanks

@joojaa
revolutions = 1500 rpm
mass = 0.04kg
acceleration = ~1000ms^-2
I think will use a Cam and follower mechanism

Yeah but how long is the movement of each storke. I mean its fine for a mm or so but not 100 mm

First, you have to see how doable this is.
Suppose you want your rod to move 2cm in 5 milliseconds and it weighs 10g. I suppose you want it to be stopped at that distance, so if the servo takes as long to slow down as it does to speed up, you will need it to move 1cm is 2.5milliseconds.
The power you will need can be calculated from this formula:
$ power = \frac{md^2}{t^3}$
That comes to 128 watts. As you will also have to accelerate the rotor of the servo, you’ll need at least twice that, say 260w-300w.
If a screw threaded rod is too slow, that means going with a gear wheel driving a toothed rod.
You may be better off going with a linear actuator of some kind, especially if accuracy of position is important.

Thanks for your feedback

some methods:

car tyres drag the car when they rotate. In mechanical tools one can have a circular gear against a linear gear (=straight bar with properly engineered teeth) for better accuracy
propellers in vessels and airplanes rotate and cause linear movement. The same happens in pumps, but it works only with liquids and gases.
hydraulic piston moves linearly when the system fluid pump rotates.
screws sink to wood when they are rotated or a nut advances along a bolt when one of them is rotated.
one adjusts a spanner by rotating a worm-like screw
off-road cars use winches to pull themselves out of mud
David knocked down Goliath by releasing a stone which was at first spinned in a centrifugal sling

I'm afraid you should reveal the actual construction problem to get a really useful answer.

Thanks for your feedback
